# PHP not getting new environment variables

Tags: php, windows, cmd, environment-variables

I set some new environment variables in my windows machine through CMD and tried running SET, I see my new variables:

FFMPEG=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ffmpeg.exe

But when I run PHP using exec("set"); I don't see the new variable at all despite restarting IIS. Do I have to reboot the whole machine or is there any way to "refresh" PHP to get the new variables?

Answer (score 0):

Changes made with `SET` will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session (see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)).
To permanently change a variable at the command line use `SetX` or with the GUI

```
Control Panel -> System -> Environment -> System/User Variables
```

Comment: I tried using setx MEDIA \\100.12.5.7\d\mediafolder\ but it is not setting although it prompts me with a successful msg. The only way is to use SET. I have also use setx for another variable "setx FFMPEG C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ffmpeg.exe, but still PHP doesn't seems to get it.

Comment: Only NEW instances of programs will get changes. CMD rereads the variables when started.